# Convert SpatialPoints to SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, point, data-frame

Give an object `x` of class `SpatialPoints` how do I convert it to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` ?

```
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 50 
extent      : 3187836, 3827836, -489229.3, 950770.7  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

Comment: Simply add a data.frame of attributes to the points

Comment: @gene can you please give a sample?

Comment: [Spatial Data in R: Vector Data](http://www.nickeubank.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/RGIS1_SpatialDataTypes_part1_vectorData.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with `data.frame` to coerce into the desired object.

```
library(sp)
x <- SpatialPoints( rbind(c(1.5, 2), c(2.5, 2), c(0.5, 0.5), c(1, 0.25), 
                          c(1.5, 0), c(2, 0), c(2.5, 0), c(3, 0.25), 
                          c(3.5, 0.5)))
  class(x)
```

Here we create a `data.frame` within the call to `SpatialPointsDataFrame` that contains a sequential ID column based on the number of points. This could be anything as long as the row/column dimensions are correct. To ensure that the row names match you can pull them from the SpatialPoints object and assign them to the data.frame using the row.names argument.

```
x <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(x, data.frame(row.names=row.names(x),
                        ID=1:length(x)))
  class(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Given `x` a `SpatialPoints` object:

```
> x
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 50 
extent      : 0.0006317429, 0.9926516, 0.02675848, 0.9901886  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

...you can convert to `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with `as`:

```
> as(x,"SpatialPointsDataFrame")
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 50 
extent      : 0.0006317429, 0.9926516, 0.02675848, 0.9901886  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 0
>
```

but note that gives you a SpatialDataFrame with 50 points but seemingly no rows or columns and any attempt to assign 50 data values will fail:

```
> dim(xs)
[1] 0 0
> xs$ID=1:50
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = 1:50) : 
  replacement has 50 rows, data has 0
```

[Edit: **after trying to track down the code that does this in `sp` I discovered that this coercing method is introduced by attaching the *`raster`* package**  - otherwise you get an immediate error...]

You can fix this by assigning to the `@data` slot with a data frame of the right number of rows:

```
> xs@data = data.frame(ID=1:50)
> xs
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 50 
extent      : 0.0006317429, 0.9926516, 0.02675848, 0.9901886  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : ID 
min values  :  1 
max values  : 50
```

and then you can add columns as normal for a data frame:

```
> xs$ZZZ = runif(50)
>
```

Alternatively if you have a data frame you want to put on the points at construction time, use the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` constructor with points and data:

```
> xs = SpatialPointsDataFrame(x, data.frame(ID=1:50,ZZZ=runif(50)))
> xs
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 50 
extent      : 0.0006317429, 0.9926516, 0.02675848, 0.9901886  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       : ID,                ZZZ 
min values  :  1, 0.0235063806176186 
max values  : 50,  0.983690821100026 
>
```